# Help to analyze the ”pronombre relativo" in the sentence

Tags: gramática, pronombres

### Question

What do the pronombres relativos refer to in the sentence and what are the clues? Also please help to correct the translation.

### Sentence

> Al interpretar las obras, en muchos casos es necesario repetir trozos ya ejecutados, **lo** cual se indica por medio de señales o signos, **siendo** los principales **los** que se indican a continuación, sobre **los** cuales y para mejor distinguirlos colocamos una **crucecita**.

### Translation

To interpret the music, in many things it is necessary to repeat the music chart we just played, (la cual: la = repeat?) which is indicated by signal or signs, (siendo: subject of 'ser' are signo/señales?), being the main signs which indicate to continue, (sobre los cuales: los = signo/señales?) over those signs and to better distinguish them, we place a cross.

[image]

Comment: "La cual" doesn't match and should be "lo cual": the original typography doesn't help a lot. Your understanding is right: it refers to the need to repeat, so a "which" is enough

Answer (score 3):

The sentence in your music book:

> Al interpretar las obras, en muchos casos es necesario repetir trozos ya ejecutados, **lo cual se indica** por medio de señales o signos, **siendo** los principales los que se indican a continuación, **sobre los cuale**s y para mejor distinguirlos colocamos una crucecita.

"lo cual se indica" -- here, "lo cual" refers to the whole phrase ("repetir trozos ya ejecutados").

The part that starts with "siendo" means: *the principal [most important] of these being* etc.

"Sobre los cuales etc." means "above which, and in order to make more of a distinction, we put a small cross."  It modifies "los que se indican a continuación."

Not a well written sentence.  It reminds me of spaghetti code.

Here is what it means in a loose translation, which I include here assuming you are a music student and would like to capture the basic idea of the paragraph:

> When interpreting music, it is often necessary to repeat a figure, and this is indicated through special symbols, the most common of which are shown below, with a cross above each one, to make them easier to recognize.

I assume you are also a student of Spanish and needed some help hacking your way through what is rather a jungle of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

the thing is that "lo cual" should be trated as a block, since the article is essential to know the gender, and consequently to know what "cual" refers to. In fact, the word "cual" alone does not make sense with this meaning.